# Flutter 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a simple music player type app. I am facing an issue when my audio completed the time it's showing

`'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 166 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.`

My code

```
                     Expanded(
                        child: Slider(
                          activeColor: Color(0xffe7ad29),
                          inactiveColor: Color(0xFF707070),
                          value: model.playerBarValue,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            model.seekFromBar(val);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),

class PlayerProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final player = AssetsAudioPlayer();
  String link;
  Duration playerTimeNow = Duration(seconds: 0);
  Duration playerLength;
  double playerBarValue = 0.0;
  Episode episode;
  Item podcastInfo;

  String episodeName, episodeThumbnail;

  bool isPlaying = false;

  PlayerProvider() {
    updateState();
  }

  play() async {
    print("Started Playing");
    // Stop previous playing
    player.stop();
    playerTimeNow = Duration(seconds: 0);
    isPlaying = false;

    // link = updateLinkToHttps(link);
    print(link);
    final audio = Audio.network(
      link,
      metas: Metas(
        title: podcastInfo.collectionName,
        artist: podcastInfo.artistName,
        album: podcastInfo.trackName,
        image: MetasImage.network(podcastInfo.artworkUrl600),
        //can be MetasImage.network
      ),
    );

    var duration = await player.open(
      audio,
      showNotification: true,
      notificationSettings: NotificationSettings(
          //seekBarEnabled: false,
          //stopEnabled: true,
          //customStopAction: (player){
          //  player.stop();
          //}
          //prevEnabled: false,
          customNextAction: (player) {
        print("next1");
        forward();
      }, customPrevAction: (player) {
        print("next2");
        backword();
      }
          //customStopIcon: AndroidResDrawable(name: "ic_stop_custom"),
          //customPauseIcon: AndroidResDrawable(name:"ic_pause_custom"),
          //customPlayIcon: AndroidResDrawable(name:"ic_play_custom"),
          ),
    );
    isPlaying = true;

    // player.play(); // Usually you don't want to wait for playback to finish.
    print("started");
    setState();
  }

  pause() async {
    await player.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
    print("paused");
    setState();
  }

  resume() async {
    //TODO: Setup resume
    await player.seek(playerTimeNow);
    player.play();
    isPlaying = true;
  }

  speed(double val) async {
    print(val);
    //TODO: Setup resume
    await player.setPlaySpeed(val);
    isPlaying = true;
  }

  updateState() {
    player.currentPosition.listen((event) {
      playerTimeNow = event;
      updatePlayerBar();
    });
  }

  updatePlayerBar() {
    int totalLengthInMilliSeconds = playerLength.inMilliseconds;
    int totalPlayedInMilliSeconds = playerTimeNow.inMilliseconds;
    double newPlayerBarValue =
        totalPlayedInMilliSeconds / totalLengthInMilliSeconds;
    playerBarValue = newPlayerBarValue;
    // print(playerBarValue);
    // print(playerTimeNow);
    // print(playerLength);
    // print(playerLength);
    // if (playerLength == playerTimeNow) {
    //   print('Finish');
    //   player.stop();
    // }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  forward() async {
    //TODO: Check if at-least 10 seconds are left;
    if (playerTimeNow + Duration(seconds: 10) < playerLength)
      await player.seek(playerTimeNow + Duration(seconds: 10));
    else
      await player.seek(playerLength);
    print("Forwarded 10 seconds");
  }

  backword() async {
    Duration back = playerTimeNow.inSeconds > 10
        ? playerTimeNow - Duration(seconds: 10)
        : Duration(seconds: 0);
    await player.seek(back);
    print("Backwarded 10 seconds");
  }

  seekFromBar(double val) async {
    double totalMillis = playerLength.inMilliseconds * val;
    int newMillis = totalMillis.toInt();
    Duration newSeekLocations = Duration(milliseconds: newMillis);
    await player.seek(newSeekLocations);
    print("Seek from Bar");
  }

  setState() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

When time is finished of player then it's showing this error on red screen. I need to know the fix of this? Mean when it's finished time go to 0 or something. The issue is on the slider I think because if I back from the red screen then my slider goes to zero.

Comment: Does any solution in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29896) work for you?

Comment: Firstly you need to make sure that the value you provide to the slider should be between 0 to 1. Then if the value exceeds 1, you can add a handler in the onChanged function to reset it to 0 or something.

Comment: You can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/clamp.html to clamp it: value.clamp(0.0, 1.0)

Comment: You should start debugging this either with a debugger or by modifying `flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider.dart` and temporarily modifying that `assert` to print the values of `value`, `min`, and `max`.

Answer (score 1):

check thet the value of model.playerBarValue is neither Nan or null, and set a max value for the slider.

```
Slider(
      value: model.playerBarValue.isNaN==true || model.playerBarValue==null? 0 : model.playerBarValue,
      min: 0.0,
      max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble() + 1.0,
      onChanged: (value) {
       . . .
      },
)
```